# "MIDI access requested" em página especifica

Tags: suporte, bug, status-nãorepro

Página solicitando controle sobre os dispositivos áudio MIDI:

[image: MIDI access requested]

Ocorreu quando fui testar um link que compartilhei de uma resposta minha: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198574/como-corrigir-o-encoding-do-requests-em-python/198577#198577)

Creio que seja algo do *googleads* ou do *reCAPTCHA*, também pode ser um problema do Opera, mas por via das dúvidas a pergunta aqui servirá para futuros visitantes.

Comment: mano, vc tá com vírus, recomendo o programa `format` do DOS, boa sorte

Comment: Talvez um ad tentando gerar uma fingerprint do seu ambiente?

Comment: @bfavaretto eu tentei, mas não consegui reproduzir novamente a mensagem

Comment: Vou pedir pro Gabe ver se tem chance de algum código do site (ou ad) ter gerado isso.

Answer (score 2):

Nós não servimos ads no SOpt. O que, junto do imenso controle editorial que exercemos sobre publicidade, torna difícil que seja algo assim aconteça.

O alerta é esquisito, sem dúvidas, mas sabemos que não foi nada no nosso build (não planejamos permitir controle de votos por interface MIDI pelo menos até 2023), e também não foi nenhuma propaganda que passou por todos os nossos filtros...

Sem conseguir reproduzir o problema infelizmente não temos muito o que fazer.

---

<sup>1. **Nota não-científica**:</sup> Eu também uso Opera e não recebi nenhum alerta assim

Comment: Eu não uso adblock no SOpt, mas o ativei no site principal e peguei o log, são os seguintes: ados.js, analytics.js, quant.js e beacon.js. O qual eu suspeito é o ados.js (site https://adzerk.com). Não estou afirmando que foi ele, pode ter sido uma extensão para o navegador (se bem que neste caso teria ocorrido em outros site, o que nunca notei). Mas no geral o ados.js é a unica coisa mais estranha e é justamente usada com o propósito de ads, mesmo que não sirvam, não quer dizer que não seja coletado algo.

Comment: Nós usamos o AdOS do Adzerk há bastante tempo, e o arquivo servido aqui é o mesmo que em qualquer outro site da rede. Então, se algo de esquisito estivesse ocorrendo nele, o mais provável é que afetaria todos os outros sites, não apenas aqui.

Comment: comportamento de injeção e manutenção ou coisas assim podem ser aleatórios, como pode ser algo do analytics, felizmente não ocorreu novamente, mas uma coisa é certa, isto só ocorreu na página que linkei. Vamos deixar em stand-by até poder obter mais informações (se tornar a ocorrer).

Comment: Em 2023, vocês vão agendar uma reunião para decidir sobre o controle de votos por interface MIDI?

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim. E implementar em 6-8 semanas