# Por motivos de segurança, não é permitido enquadramento. Clique em OK para remover os quadros

Tags: suporte, segurança

Apareceu esta mensagem para mim:

> Por motivos de segurança, não é permitido enquadramento. Clique em OK
>   para remover os quadros.

Mas não entendi o motivo, estava mexendo no site como normalmente eu mexo, qual é o motivo desta mensagem?

[image: A imagem]

Comment: Também recebi essa mensagem ontem. [Tem uma questão no meta do SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265627/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-on).

Comment: Parece um bug, mas pode ter a causa alguma coisa na sua máquina ou navegador que faça modificações na página. Com qual frequência a mensagem aparece? É em todas as páginas? Ocorre se usar um navegador diferente?

Comment: Só apareceu uma vez, eu não uso nada de especial no navegador, nem extensões eu tenho.

Comment: Apareceu aqui também.. Mensagem estranha

Comment: Pode ser algum dos AD (advertising) do site, um dia recebi essa mensagem: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5933/3635, não consegui descobrir a origem, mas tudo me levou a crer que era algum AD mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [resposta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265726) foi postada no meta.SOen que em resumo se traduz (em tradução livre):

> Essa mensagem é o resultado de um código escrito especificamente para verificar se outros sites estão abrindo os sites da Stack Exchange Network em um iframe.
>   (...)
>
> A questão é que alguma coisa está injetando um iframe nas páginas que seu dispositivo está visitando... (...)

A resposta menciona também algumas possibilidades:

- Algum tipo de malware;
- O provedor (ISP);
- O roteador de alguma maneira;

Eu acrescentaria ainda:

- alguma extensão do browser;

Comment: Nos não usamos iframe, você sabe porque apareceu?

Comment: @WictorChaves atualizei a resposta com as possibilidades. Infelizmente não sei mais nada. Mas tentaria verificar o código fonte quando a mensgem aparecesse novamente.

Comment: ou AD (AD = advertising / propagandas injetadas)

Answer (score 5):

Acabou de ocorrer comigo, foi no momento de carregar o AD aparentemente, ocorreu assim:

- Eu estava lendo esta pergunta e respostas [TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248137/typeerror-effect-is-not-a-function)
- Então cliquei no link que levava ao perfil do AP
- Apertei <kbd>Backscape</kbd> para voltar a página anterior, então ocorreu a tal mensagem

Felizmente o scroll estava posicionado, notei que o AD e o editor para postar resposta não estavam carregados e em quanto o `alert` estava ativo não carregaram (normal do congelamento, conforme os navegadores funciona).

Então de duas uma, ou é um código no editor de texto ou é um código no AD, claro que existe a possibilidade de ser um add-on, mas me parece muita coincidência.

> PS: problema semelhante ["MIDI access requested" em página especifica](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5933/3635)

Detalhes:

- Windows 8.1
- Opera 48 (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/48.0.2685.50)

Add-ons no momento que injeta scripts em todos sites ([**`<all_urls>`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)):

- https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/capture-webpage-screenshot-fireshot/
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm

Como na resposta já citada em:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265627/1518921

Esse código é nativo dos sites da rede, o código deve ser algo **semelhante** a isto:

```js
if (!(parent && parent.WebPlayer) && top != self) {
    top.location.replace(document.location);
    alert('For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.');
}
```

No entanto para o erro ocorrer de fato eu teria que ter aberto em um IFRAME ou FRAME, o que não é o caso, o problema ocorreu no <kbd>Backscape</kbd>, logo na primeira vez que acessei estava normal, não teria sentido.

O que faz pensar em 3 possibilidades:

- BUG: alguém acidentalmente alterou uma das variáveis nativas do javascript `self`, `top` e `parent`, ou o código foi modificado (estou olhando o "source")
- O AD também pode tem prevenção de "injeção" ou algo assim e na verdade é ele quem não esta funcionando muito bem, visando que **creio eu** já ter havido outras falhas.
- Pode ser um BUG até mesmo do jQuery (1.12.4) ou dos navegadores baseados em Chrome que afeta de alguma maneira o `self` ou o `top`

### Observação 1

o código de checagem hoje esta assim:

```js
if (window.StackExchange = {}, window.jQuery && ! function(e) {
        var t = function(e) {
            e = e.toLowerCase();
            var t = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(e) || /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(e) || /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(e) || /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec(e) || e.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec(e) || [];
            return {
                "browser": t[1] || "",
                "version": t[2] || "0"
            }
        };
        if (!e.browser) {
            var n = t(navigator.userAgent),
                i = {};
            n.browser && (i[n.browser] = !0, i.version = n.version), i.chrome ? i.webkit = !0 : i.webkit && (i.safari = !0), e.browser = i
        }
    }(jQuery), top != self) throw top.location.replace(document.location), $(function() {
    $("head").add("body").remove()
}), alert("Por motivos de seguranÃ§a, nÃ£o Ã© permitido enquadramento. Clique em OK para remover os quadros."), new Error;
```

É importante notar que as virgulas dentro do if são desconsideradas e só após a ultima virgula é que é testado no if, por exemplo:

```js
if (false, false, false, true) {
    console.log("Olá");
}
```

Então no caso o código acima seria algo como isto para entendimento de como funciona:

```js
if (top != self) {
    //isto talvez redirecione, só não sei o porque do throw
    throw top.location.replace(document.location);

    // Pega o body e head e remove (seria o mesmo que $("head,body").remove())
    $(function() {
        $("head").add("body").remove()
    });

    //Mensagem de aviso
    alert("Por motivos de seguranÃ§a, nÃ£o Ã© permitido enquadramento. Clique em OK para remover os quadros.");

    //Gera um erro pra provavelmente bloquear outros scripts
    new Error;
}
```

### Observação 2

E antes que ocorra alguma negação de que o SOpt não serve AD, olhando o código fonte da "propaganda" que aparece na coluna lateral do site encontrei isto:

[image: indicios]

Ou seja, existe googlead, logo é algo que pode estar ocasionando a falha talvez, não posso afirmar nada.

Comment: Você consegue reproduzir o problema consistentemente?

Comment: @EMBarbosa não, se eu conseguisse provavelmente eu saberia qual a origem do problema, estou apenas indagando que se a falha ocorreu comigo também é muita coincidência, pois essa mensagem `top!=self` não faz sentido a injeção de código disparar algo, então add-on é um pouco improvável, mas pode ser algo que afetou o `window.top` ou `window.self` como pode ter sido as possíveis mudanças no Chrome 61 (chromium) que inclusive afetaram a funcionalidade do scroll via javascript. Não dá pra afirmar nada, só falei como o erro ocorreu comigo e informei que o AD travou no exato momento.